# Does expl3 key-setting syntax have an equivalent of TikZ/PGF's .cd?

Tags: expl3, latex3, pgfkeys, key-value, l3keys

This question has the following form: 'I know how to do X using Y. I can also do X using Z but not so elegantly as using Y. Can I do X using Z in the same way that I can do X using Y, for a more elegant Z-based solution?'

In this case, Y is TikZ/PGF and Z is `expl3` syntax.

Using PGF keys, I can define and/or set a group of keys under a particular path without having to repeatedly specify the path. One way to do this is to use `.cd` to change the current path until further notice.

```
<path specification>/.cd,
<definition of key 1>,
<definition of key 2>,
<set key 1>,
<set key 2>,
```

This makes it possible to provide an easy interface for setting a group of keys.

```
<group key name>/.code={
  \tikzset{%
    <path specification>/.cd,
    #1
  }
},
```

Does the `expl3` syntax offer an equivalent of `.cd` and, if so, what is it?

I can emulate the effect I want by using distinct `\keys_define:nn` commands for each relevant path, but this seems a somewhat inelegant solution so I'm wondering if I'm missing a more straightforward facility.

MWE showing TikZ case and Expl3 emulation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\tikzset{%
  my keys/.code={
    \tikzset{%
      /top/middle/bottom/.cd,
      #1
    }
  },
  /top/middle/bottom/.cd,
  key 1/.store in=\keyone,
  key 2/.store in=\keytwo,
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { top / middle / bottom }
{
  key~1 .tl_set:N = \l_module_keyone_tl,
  key~2 .tl_set:N = \l_module_keytwo_tl,
}
\keys_define:nn { top }
{
  my~keys .code:n = {
    \keys_set:nn { top / middle / bottom } { #1 }
  }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \topset { m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { top } { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \showkeyone {} { \l_module_keyone_tl }
\NewDocumentCommand \showkeytwo {} { \l_module_keytwo_tl }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  my keys={%
    key 1=Arrangement,
    key 2=Ascension,
  },
}%
\topset{%
  my keys={%
    key 1=Arrangement,
    key 2=Ascension,
  },
}%
TikZ/PGF:

\keyone{}
\keytwo

Expl3:

\showkeyone{}
\showkeytwo
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: TikZ/Expl3]

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: no.

The idea of using a keyval approach to setting up keys themselves was (that I know of) first implemented for TeX in `pgfkeys`. When writing `l3keys` I looked very hard at this for a model of the most convenient way to create keys and to adjust their behaviour. However, `l3keys` is not simply a re-implementation of `pgfkeys` (indeed, there are some outstanding issues in `l3keys` that may stem from this!). In particular, whilst `pgfkeys` is object-oriented, that is not true for `l3keys`. In `pgfkeys` there is no distinction between 'creating keys' and 'setting keys' and so it is possible to have the `.cd` concept. On the other hand, in `l3keys` the two concepts are deliberately separate. This follows the model of `keyval` (with `\define@key` and `\setkeys`).

Comment: Thanks. I never did get on with **keyval**... ;). I can see the case for separating definition and setting of keys. I don't entirely understand why this makes something like `.cd` impossible. In fact, something like `.cd` would make it easier to keep definition and setting distinct, from my point of view, because I wouldn't then need to use `\keys_set:nn` inside `\keys_define:nn` at all. Or do you mean that it is impossible to implement something like this?

Comment: @cfr in theory, it doesn't make something `.cd`-like impossible to do, but since `l3keys` doesn't interpret key names other than looking them up during `\keys_set:nn`, one can't use a mechanism like in `pgfkeys`. Instead, what one would have to create would be a key that changes the current key path (so alters the effects of the first argument of `\keys_set:nn`). But a mechanism like this isn't implemented, afaik.